# В какое место засунуть Enum, чтобы иметь доступ к нему отовсюду?

Tags: c#

После Java небольшая дизориентация, там я мог просто поместить в отдельный файл и получать доступ свободно, но тут так не получается. Статический Enum у класса создать нельзя, как поступить? Если более точно о цели, то мне нужно передавать Enum как параметр в функцию при вызове из другого класса.

Comment: >там я мог просто поместить в отдельный файл и получать доступ свободно

делайте так же, что вам мешает?

Comment: просто в **namespace**-е пишите свой enum и его используете

Comment: Ошибка 1 Несовместимость по доступности: доступность типа параметра 'ChineseOpenFacePoker.Mod' ниже доступности метода 'ChineseOpenFacePoker.Views.GameWindow.GameWindow(ChineseOpenFacePoker.Mod)' C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\проект\Новая папка\ChineseOpenFacePoker\ChineseOpenFacePoker\Views\GameWindow.xaml.cs 


namespace своего enum в класс вызываемого метода внес, не знаю в чем проблема

Comment: Код в студию?

Comment: скорее всего вы засунули public enum в класс с меньшим уровнем доступа. Enum не обязательно в классе объявлять, его можно вне класса создать и будет вам счастье, либо сделайте свой класс public'ом

Answer (score 8):

`enum` это такой же тип как и все остальное. Сделайте его публичным, далее импортируйте через `namespace` и все. В чем проблема то?